# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSocketFactory is null

Tags: java, ssl, client-certificates

I have a problem with the following code...

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:\\ClientKeyStore\\ClientKeyStore.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\ClientKeyStore\\ClientKeyStore.keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "keystorepass");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "truststorepass");

SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
URL url = new URL("https://url.com");
HttpsURLConnection httpCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setSSLSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);
OutputStream out=httpCon.getOutputStream();
```

I tried to set the trust store, keystore and other properties of SSL context using the `System.setProperty(key,value)` method, but I'm getting the following error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.
```

Could someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: What code/settings do you use to get this?

Comment: @Bruno: Check the code now. I edited the post.

Comment: Have you previously called `SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()` before the properties were set?

Comment: No I haven't called SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() before setting the system properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try forward slashes for the paths even on windows:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:/ClientKeyStore/ClientKeyStore.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:/ClientKeyStore/ClientKeyStore.keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "keystorepass");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "truststorepass");


SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
```

Is this all your code? Your properties look fine and I was able to use your example to create a socket factory.

Comment: I changed the code a little again. I don't have trouble with setting properties but even though I set the properties the SSLSocketFactory object is staying to be null. Is there anything I can do on server side or in my local system settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my websphere 8.5 / ibm java 1.7 setup.

In my case it was caused by the JREs <JRE_HOME>\lib\security\java.security file.

In my case the file said...

```
ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=IbmX509
ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX
```

The PKIX value looked suspicious so I changed this line of the file to...

```
ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm=IbmX509
```

When I restarted the websphere server the connection worked.