# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket

Tags: java, websphere, apache-axis

We have an application to consume webservice over SSL.
We have created stub using AXIS2 1.6.2 and application is deployed in websphere 8.5.5.4.
Below error is thrown when it initiates the request over SSL.
Please advise whether any extra settings required on the Websphere side.

```
´9/23/15 0:50:17:219 SGT] 000001f1 HttpMethodDir I     org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry I/O     exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLException) caught when processing request:     SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if     javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket     and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.
[9/23/15 0:50:17:219 SGT] 000001f1 HttpMethodDir I     org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry     Retrying request
[9/23/15 0:50:17:219 SGT] 000001f1 HttpMethodDir I org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLException) caught when processing request: SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.
[9/23/15 0:50:17:219 SGT] 000001f1 HttpMethodDir I org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry Retrying request
[9/23/15 0:50:17:219 SGT] 000001f1 HttpMethodDir I org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry I/O exception (javax.net.ssl.SSLException) caught when processing request: SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.
[9/23/15 0:50:17:219 SGT] 000001f1 HttpMethodDir I org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry Retrying request
[9/23/15 0:50:17:219 SGT] 000001f1 HTTPSender    I org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender sendViaPost Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://10.91.35.41:37157/Services/EventInq]
                           javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.
          at com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:334)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
          at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:116)
          at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:130)
          at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
          at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
          at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
          at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
          at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
          at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
          at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
          at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
          at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
          at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
          at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
          at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
          at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
          at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
          at com.avaya.aps.cep.stub.EventInqStub.eventInq(EventInqStub.java:220)
          at com.avaya.aps.selfservice.host.services.impl.CEPServiceImpl.getCEPEventDetails(CEPServiceImpl.java:138)
          at flow.CEPLookup.servletImplementation(CEPLookup.java:65)
          at com.avaya.sce.runtime.BasicServlet.handleRequest(BasicServlet.java:99)
          at com.avaya.sce.runtime.AppServlet.processRequest(AppServlet.java:96)
          at com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.requestHandler(SCEServlet.java:285)
          at com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.doPost(SCEServlet.java:190)
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
          at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
          at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
          at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
          at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
          at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1111)
          at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3901)
          at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
          at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
          at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
          at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
          at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
          at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
          at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
          at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
          at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
          at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
          at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
          at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
          at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
              at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
          at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
          at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
              at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)

[9/23/15 0:50:17:219 SGT] 000001f1 SystemOut     O -     [12423435435353]AxisFault while connecting to CEPSSLSocketFactory is     null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is     called to create a socket and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.
´
```

Comment: Do you have security enabled on your server? Are you setting javax.net.ssl.* properties? To which truststore you added signer certificate from the server you are trying to connect?

Comment: Setting the following following javax.net.ssl.* details are set in application and websphere console as well.

Comment: Setting the following following javax.net.ssl.* details are set in application and websphere console as well.                                                                  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
     trustStoreD:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext/certs.jks);
   System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",
     pass123);                                                     signer certificate is added to key store referred. I need to check with websphere team on the security part.

Comment: So did you find a solution for this issue as I am facing it now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well in my case I had to change the JREs <JRE_HOME>\lib\security\java.security file.

See [javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSocketFactory is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921941/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-sslsocketfactory-is-null/53156775#53156775)